# Prove that A',B',C' are in a straight line.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

[image: Question Image]

Be an ABC triangle and a point P of your plane. The perpendiculars to PA, PB and PC, traced by P, intersect the BC, CA and AB sides at three points, A ', B' and C '. Prove that these points are in a straight line.

Can someone explain me how to do this question?
I just found that 
$\angle APB'=\angle A'PB\\
\angle B'PC=\angle BPC'$
My first idea was to use Analytic Geometry, but I don't know what I have to do...
Thanks for antetion.
If someone has a solution by eucliidean geometry, I will love it!

Comment: I don't understand.  If ABC is a triangle and P is not on it then the feet of the perpendiculars from P to the sides of ABC are NOT co-linear.

Comment: The question is confused, but we need to prove that the perpendiculars from P to PA, PB, PC, intersects the sides BC, AC, AB, in points A', B', C', and we need to prove that A', B', C' are co-linears (the picture show this).

Comment: What is a perpendicular from P to PA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be probably a nice Euclidean solution, however, I would like to show you a short vector one.

Let $P$ be the origin and points $A,B,C$ have coordinates $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}$. Let's say that $BA'/BC=\alpha$, then the coordinate of $A'$:
$$
\mathbf{a'}=\mathbf{b}+\alpha(\mathbf c-\mathbf b).
$$
By construction, we want $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a'}=0$, so 
$$
(\mathbf{b}+\alpha(\mathbf c-\mathbf b))\mathbf a=0,\\
\alpha=-\frac{\mathbf a\mathbf b}{\mathbf a\mathbf c-\mathbf a\mathbf b}.
$$
Then, we can find that
$$
\frac{BA'}{A'C} = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} = -\frac{\mathbf a\mathbf b}{\mathbf a\mathbf c}.
$$
By analogy, $CB'/B'A=-\mathbf b\mathbf c/\mathbf a\mathbf b$ and $AC'/C'B=-\mathbf a\mathbf c/\mathbf b\mathbf c$.

Finally, since
$$
\frac{BA'}{A'C}\frac{CB'}{B'A}\frac{AC'}{C'B}=-1,
$$
by [Menelaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) we can conclude that $A',B',C'$ are colinear.